# Series Indexing Question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n\right)$  = ln(2)

I am confused as to how this indexing works. From what I understand, changing the index from 0 to 1 means that all "n" should be replaced by (n-1).

My initial thought was that since (-1)^(n+1) is alternating, this rule does not apply to it, but after seeing other examples online I have become even more confused.

Would the answerer be so kind as to explain how this makes sense and perhaps go more in depth on how index changes affect the series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is merely a matter of notation, and does not depend on whether the series is alternating or not.

Starting with $\;S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\,$, let $\,m=n+1\,$, then the lower limit of summation $\,n=0\,$ maps to $\,m=1\,$ and the upper limit remains $\,\infty\,$, so $\;S=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m}\,$ and also $\,S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\,$ since the name/tag of the summation variable is irrelevant.

As $\,(-1)^n=-(-1)^{n+1}\,$, the latter can also be written as $\;S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\,$.